# random access to re-creatable randomly generated big data

Tags: python, random, bigdata, dynamically-generated

I need to generate much data of mostly basic data types for stress testing NoSQL databases (Cassandra right now, maybe others in future). I also need to be able to re-create this randomly created data in the future and, more problematicly, retrieve random entries from this already generated data to generate queries.

Re-creating the data itself imposes no problem via providing the same seed to the randomness generator. The hard part is retrieving a random item from the generated data. The obious way would be to store all of it in a data structure, but we are talking about potentially GBs of data, so this should not be an option (or am I wrong here?).

The random re-generation of previously generated items should also be as fast as possible, synchonisable over different threads and ideally provide a way to specify the underlaying distribution for both the generated data and the selection of test data items.

**[edit]** I just found out, that the `random.jumpahead(n)`-function might come in handy, only problem is it does not work with the pseudo number generator (PNGR) used since python 2.3. But the old one is still available (`random.WichmannHill()`), where I could just "jump ahead" n steps from my initial seed.

And just to be clear: I'm using python 2.7.

**[edit2]** What this question might boil down to is skipping *n* generation steps. You can do it with the original PNGR with some code like I found [here](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/504030-random-jumpahead-how-jump-ahead-exactly-n-steps):

```
def skip(n):
    for _ in xrange(n):
        random.random()
```

But, as said in the source and tested by me, this is only efficient for *n*<~100.000, which is way to small. Using `random.WichmannHill()` I can use `jumpahead(n)` for any *n* with the same perfomance.

Comment: Do you have to keep all of the data around? Can you destroy data you don't intend to use for your randomly generated queries?

Comment: No, the data can be destroyed as soon as it is inserted into the database.

Comment: You could use some generator that's **designed** for jumpahead; google "Parallel Random Numbers: As Easy as 1, 2, 3" - the only gotcha is that since you're using python you'll likely find block ciphers faster than the other suggestions (because they'll typically be implemented in C)

Answer (score 1):

If you already know 1) the number of entries you will be generating, and 2) the number of random entries you need from that data, you could just obtain the random entries as you are generating them, storing only those in a data structure.

Say you need to create a million entries for your NoSQL database, and you know you'll want to grab 100 random items out of there to test queries. You can generate 100 random numbers between 1 and 1,000,000, and as you're generating the entries for your stress test, you can take the entries that match up with your randomly-generated numbers and store those specific ones in a data structure. Alternately, you can just save a randomly generated entry to your data structure with some probability `m/n`, where `m` is the number of random test queries you need, and `n` is the total volume of data you're creating.

Basically, it's going to be much easier to obtain the random data while it's being generated than to store everything and pluck data randomly from there. As for how to generate the data, that's going to probably be dependent on your NoSQL implementation and the specific data format you want to use.

EDIT: as dcorking pointed out, you don't even need to store the test items themselves in a data structure. You can just execute them as they show up while you're generating data. All you would need to store is the sequence that determines which tests get run. Or, if you don't want to run the same tests every time, you can just randomly select certain elements to be your test elements as I mentioned above, and store nothing at all.

Comment: I also came up with something similar like that, but there are at least two problems: 1) one can not increase the size of tests afterwards (but I'm still not shure if that's a problem), and 2) if I have many tests (like >10^10), or big testdata storage would be to costly.

Comment: @causaprima If storage is more expensive than generating the data, perhaps you can  store only the original randomly generated sequence numbers of the items. Then when you repeat the test, generate the data again, using only the items that appear in the sequence, and discard the rest.

Comment: @dcorking I don't understand what you mean, could you rephrase it? And to be more precise: space for storage is limited in RAM, and storage in the file system might need to much time when needing >15.000 test items.

Comment: @causaprima TheSoundDefense's answer seems a sensible approach to the question. Each time you generate data from a fixed seed, you will get the same data _in_the_same_order. For a reason I don't understand, you want to take a random sample, of b items, from your data, and you want that to be the same too, I think. But you have no space to store that random sample. You don't need to - you just keep the b random numbers, or even the seed for those, and generate the new data each time. Your data flow doesn't need to be fast to stress test the db, it just needs to be faster than the db.

Comment: The reason for a random sample b of already randomly sampled data n is that I need a guarantee that the queried data is actually present in the database. Storing all the n seeds is a better approach than storing b complete items, but still might be to big, I need to do some tests with this. Thanks for the idea, might help a lot!

Comment: @causaprima Well, important question: do you need to re-use your random selections later? Or can they be randomly determined every time? There may be no need to store anything at all.

Comment: @TheSoundDefense I need to re-use the selection. The idea is to provide a comparable test set (data and queries) without providing the actual data, just some configuration (tables, queries and seed).